# $(window).height() is typed to return number | undefined

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following in typescript (3.9.5):

```
const height: number = $(window).height();
```

This fails with:

```
TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I am using the following relevant packages:

```
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.0"
```

What is the proper way to handle this in typescript?

Comment: I guess it is generic, didnt check but maybe you can add a definition for $<BrowserView> ... or append `as number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type of `height`. It can be inferred.

However, if you want to ensure that `height` is explicity of type `number`, you need to handle the case where the result of `$(window).height()` returns `undefined`.

Example:

```
const height: number = $(window).height() || 0
```

Alternatively, infer the type

```
// type of height will be number | undefined
const height = $(window).height()
```

The last alternative is to force the typing system to do what you want. This is normally not good practice, but if you know for sure that the result is a number, you can do this:

```
// Not the preferred way, but it's possible.
const height = ($(window).height() as number)
```